# salt-api (cherrypy) returns HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error when trying to log in

Tags: cherrypy, salt-stack

salt-api returns HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error when trying to log in:

```
curl -si localhost:8000/login         -H "Accept: application/json"         -d username='<notshown>'         -d password='<notshown>'         -d eauth='pam'
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Length: 1607
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: GET, POST
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: CherryPy/3.2.2
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Date: Thu, 14 Apr 2016 13:23:49 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Auth-Token: 6a529d945c6654848c531337c1a1193f8635b482
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Set-Cookie: session_id=6a529d945c6654848c531337c1a1193f8635b482; expires=Thu, 14 Apr 2016 23:23:49 GMT; Path=/

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
    <title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #powered_by {
        margin-top: 20px;
        border-top: 2px solid black;
        font-style: italic;
    }

    #traceback {
        color: red;
    }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <h2>500 Internal Server Error</h2>
        <p>Configuration for external_auth could not be read.</p>
        <pre id="traceback">Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 656, in respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 188, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/netapi/rest_cherrypy/app.py", line 506, in hypermedia_handler
    ret = cherrypy.serving.request._hypermedia_inner_handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 34, in __call__
    return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/netapi/rest_cherrypy/app.py", line 1525, in POST
    'Configuration for external_auth could not be read.')
HTTPError: (500, 'Configuration for external_auth could not be read.')
</pre>
    <div id="powered_by">
    <span>Powered by <a href="http://www.cherrypy.org">CherryPy 3.2.2</a></span>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When you enter the wrong credentials, the error is different so it definitely knows that the credentials entered before are correct:

```
curl -si localhost:8000/login         -H "Accept: application/json"         -d username='<notshown>'         -d password='<notshown>'         -d eauth='pam'
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 1586
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: GET, POST
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: CherryPy/3.2.2
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Date: Thu, 14 Apr 2016 13:23:34 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Set-Cookie: session_id=b71f4afcc8f1caf3e0f5f33d0542c77bc1b9875a; expires=Thu, 14 Apr 2016 23:23:34 GMT; Path=/

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
    <title>401 Unauthorized</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #powered_by {
        margin-top: 20px;
        border-top: 2px solid black;
        font-style: italic;
    }

    #traceback {
        color: red;
    }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <h2>401 Unauthorized</h2>
        <p>Could not authenticate using provided credentials</p>
        <pre id="traceback">Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 656, in respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 188, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/netapi/rest_cherrypy/app.py", line 506, in hypermedia_handler
    ret = cherrypy.serving.request._hypermedia_inner_handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 34, in __call__
    return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/netapi/rest_cherrypy/app.py", line 1497, in POST
    'Could not authenticate using provided credentials')
HTTPError: (401, 'Could not authenticate using provided credentials')
</pre>
    <div id="powered_by">
    <span>Powered by <a href="http://www.cherrypy.org">CherryPy 3.2.2</a></span>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

/etc/salt/master:

```
rest_cherrypy:
  port: 8000
  host: 0.0.0.0
  disable_ssl: true
  debug: true

.....

external_auth:
  pam:
    <notshownhere>:
        -.*
        - '@runner'
        - '@wheel'
```

versions used:

```
salt-api-2015.8.8-2.el6.noarch
salt-master-2015.8.8-2.el6.noarch
salt-minion-2015.8.8-2.el6.noarch
salt-2015.8.8-2.el6.noarch
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a typo in my master configuration:

I had:

```
external_auth:
  pam:
    <notshownhere>:
        -.*
        - '@runner'
        - '@wheel'
```

Shoud be:

```
external_auth:
  pam:
    <notshownhere>:
        - .*
        - '@runner'
        - '@wheel'
```